# Sound doesn't play with AVAudioPlayer, only with SKAction

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, avfoundation

I just renamed my xcode project and my sounds stopped playing with AVAoudioPlayer. However, all SKAction audio is still working. I even tried recreating the project with the new name, but

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/intro-music.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
[NSURL URLWithString:path]
```

is nil

I checked that all my files are added to the target, i.e. they are contained in Copy Bundle Resources.

help please!

Comment: check that the file is in the bundle root folder (yellow group icon in xcode) and that upper/lower case is correctly spelled, too

Comment: yes, it is in the root folder, and the spelling is correct (I can still play with SKAction). The strange thing is that when I rename my project back, AFAudioPlayer works, but whenever I change the name of the project, it doesn't anymore

Comment: Tried clean & clean build folder after rename?